# “There is already an object named 'temp_Students_636136759476987970' in the database.”

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-2008

Getting the error “There is already an object named 'temp_Students_636136759476987970' in the database.” in Entity Framework(6.2). These tables are automatically created and causing this error. Why this table is created by EF and why are they not dropped automatically.

Comment: Well logic says there was something preventing the drop.. so now it cant recreate it

Comment: I wonder... did you use an EF extension like EntityFramework.Extended, Utilities or BulkInsert? Because I am using multiple extensions, and I encounter this error daily.

Answer (score 0):

I´ve found to links that may help you:
[There is already an object named in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305273/there-is-already-an-object-named-in-the-database)
and [Entity Framework Automatic Migrations Existing Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15303542/entity-framework-automatic-migrations-existing-database)..

In general its as BugFinder said: I guess you´ve deleted/edited the table manually, which causes this error.

I dont had this error before, but I had different ones. If you delete a class and create it again with the same name, it can happen, that vs can´t create it with this name. If you delete the folder of this class at your storage, the error wan´t come again.

To find the source of EF-objects can be harder.. But if you are able to find the source of either the object, or the creation of the object, there will be a possibility to get rid of that error.

bst rgrds